# how to easily test a billing app with Google Play developer console?

Tags: javafx-8, google-play-games, gluon-mobile, javafxports, android-billing

Why this question?
I read many articles in "Google Play Developer Console" site (GPDC) but I don't understand ***how to completely test by myself an in-app billing requesting the Google Play server***, before I submit it to testers:

- I already got a licence key from Google Play. That points out that my apk file is correctly signed and that GPDC has already checked that.
- My product is **a one-time product**. So, it would be useful, before testing it with the GPDC server, that I provide an item related to this "one-time product" to GPDC, isn't it? I don't read any info about that in the GPDC help.
- Moreover, I have included the in-app billing library in my JavaFX code and I want to test it by myself (not by testers). So, the internal, alpha or production tests seem to be inapppropriate. In theses conditions, how to prepare an end-to-end test (I have already included the purchase mechanism). Then, how to test it by myself with GPDC server?

My development context is : JavaFX, Gluon Charm Down and its Gluonhq InAppBilling Service - Eclipse environment

Thanks in advance

*Note: is it possible to use the GPDC "Instant app internal test" and include only my email/name in the tester list? In this case, can I test my app loaded in my phone and then make some requests to the GPDC server?*

Answer (score 1):

Android docs actually covers this in [Test Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing).

> You do not need to list the reserved products in your application's
>   product list. Google Play already knows about the reserved product
>   IDs. Also, you do not need to upload your application to the Play
>   Console to perform static response tests with the reserved product
>   IDs. You can simply install your application on a device, log into the
>   device, and make billing requests using the reserved product IDs.

Comment: At the end, I have used neither the "static responses" or the "Android instant apps" to make a test. I use the "internal test track" in "Release Management" section of Google Play Developer console. It seems to be more appropriate to easily make a test thanks to internal testers.